# Need help dealing with subdomains and regions

Tags: subdomain

Well, i'm about creating a new set of subdomains, by countries [germany, poland..] something like

```
germany.example.com
```

the thing is , i have a database with set of data containing a country field:

```
Item1 -- PL
item2 -- PL 
item3 -- XX
item4 -- XX
```

i want that subdomain to pull the data from this specific country only, so poland.example.com will only filter data from that country.

i have my script working from the main domain example.com with a dropdown box where you can select the country and it adds cookies or /preferences to the user.

the main question is : how can i deal with the subdomain the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

### Solution

From the hosting : create a subdomain with root directory so subdomain XX.example.com should not have a folder /xx in your root directory, its directory must remain null

get the subdomain using php (explode $_SERVER Host if you want... or any other method you prefer)

process the subdomain variable from your main web script, since now you have the subdomain value (XX) you can process it using your script.

... do whatever you want with that subdomain value, like

```
   if ( $subdomain == "xx" ) ... do something here
   else .. do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

When a browser sends a request to a server, it includes a `Host:` header which tells the server which subdomain the user wants. Use this in your script to select the correct database.

Comment: yea, it got clear when i was googling that, however, now i'm having an issue including root script from the poland.example.com, since in the hosting panel, the poland subdomain has its own folder in example.com/poland, how can i make that run the root script to be able to read it later with the host

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that. You'll have to ask your hosting provider what they're doing there.